# Using variable from one method in another method in Python

Tags: python, methods

In Python, I am trying to assigne a value to a variable in one method and then add a another value to the same variable in another method. Both methods are within the same class. Here is what I am trying to achieve:

```
class Account_Balance(Account_General):
    def __init__(self, first_name, middle_name, last_name, PIN, DoB, city, address, phone_number, email):
        super().__init__(first_name, middle_name, last_name, PIN, DoB, city, address, phone_number, email)
    
    def account_balance(self):
        self.balance = 10.0 
        return self.balance
    
    def account_deposite(self, amount):
        self.amount = amount
        self.balance += self.amount
```

The output is: Attribute Error: 'Account_Balance' object has no attribute 'balance'

Where do you think I am getting it wrong? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `account_deposite` before `self.balance` has been initialized. Attributes like this should be declared and initialized in `__init__`. Try this

```
class Account_Balance(Account_General):
    def __init__(self, first_name, middle_name, last_name, PIN, DoB, city, address, phone_number, email):
        super().__init__(first_name, middle_name, last_name, PIN, DoB, city, address, phone_number, email)
        self.balance = 0.0
    
    def account_balance(self):
        self.balance = 10.0 
        return self.balance
    
    def account_deposite(self, amount):
        self.amount = amount
        self.balance += self.amount
```